# PostgreSQL Configuration for HAProxy

Tags: postgresql, haproxy

I am trying to figure out how to build a scalable database system. I settled on using postgresql and am trying to figure out how to implement load balancing. I looked into HAProxy, which I really liked. I noticed that there were multiple different configurations of postgresql http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/high-availability.html. Which one would be the best to link with HAProxy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used HAProxy for MySQL. But that was because there were no options tailor-made for MySQL. And HAProxy does a great job. For PostgreSQL, there are quite a few tailor-made options. May be you could have a look at [pgpool](http://www.pgpool.net/docs/latest/pgpool-en.html)?

Are you looking for scalability alone, or failover too? Which version of PostgreSQL are you using?

Comment: Both scalability and failover. I'll be using the latest stable version of PostgreSQL. Would you recommend pgpool over HAProxy?

Comment: Definitely pgpool. I love HAProxy. It is fast, it is sophisticated. But it is not tailor-made for a specific database. pgpool can do things like connection pooling. It can be used to replicate data (with inbuilt replication in PostgreSQL, that is no longer relevant). pgpool can also use memcache to further improve performance. It can failover to standby nodes.It does have a slightly steeper learning curve.